# How to calculate the number of damaged pieces

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a DBGrid in Delphi 7 which is linked by a table created with Paradox which contains RefBac, NumberPCSRebuts.
The RefBac can be repeated several times. I want to calculate the sum of the NumberPCSRebuts for each RefBac and insert it in the Column `PCSNonOk` exactly in the line containing the last RefBac before it changes.

I found this algorithm that does the right calculation but it inserts the result in the line just after:[the result wish i want

[image]

```
Somme:=0;
DataModule1.Ouvraison.First;
DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
Vax := DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('RefBac').value;
while (not DataModule1.Ouvraison.EOF)   do
begin
  If(DataModule1.Ouvraison.FieldByName('RefBac').Value= Vax ) then
  begin
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
    Somme:=Somme+DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('NbRebut').value;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.next;
  end else begin
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('PCS NOK').value := Somme;
    Somme := 0;
    Vax := DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('RefBac').value;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;
  end;
```

Comment: Sorry, i translated my post in english thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Somme:=0;
DataModule1.Ouvraison.First;
DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
Vax := DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('RefBac')  .value;
if not DataModule1.Ouvraison.EOF then
begin
  while (not DataModule1.Ouvraison.EOF)   do
  begin
    If(DataModule1.Ouvraison.FieldByName('RefBac').Value= Vax ) then
    begin
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
      Somme:=Somme+DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('NbRebut').value;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.next;
    end else begin
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.prev;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('PCS NOK').value := Somme;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.next;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
      Somme:=DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('NbRebut').value;
      Vax := DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('RefBac').value;
      DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;
    end;
    // deal with last record!
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Last;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Edit;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.fieldByName('PCS NOK').value := Somme;
    DataModule1.Ouvraison.Post;

  end;
```

Comment: Thaaaaannnnks , it helps me a lot Thank you very much :)